# Differential Fault Analysis of AES

Tags: aes, differential-analysis

Let's say: an error is induced into an implementation of the AES-128 to produce a faulty ciphertext. The error is a one-byte eror and is always induced on the last state byte, during round9, before the `MixColumns` operation. The induced errors are unknown and can be different. However the key is the same in both cases.

Then how can I recover 4 bytes of the last round key? Which bytes of that round key can I recover and what's their value?

```
ciphertext1 = 0xe719f8ab9e0b846f0cf2e5c32a0e5b45
faultytext1 = 0xe719f86f9e0beb6f0c97e5c38b0e5b45

ciphertext2 = 0x78f272c7cf5383085fa240236d97130f
faultytext2 = 0x78f27277cf53e7085f944023fa97130f
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your fault attack scenario correspond to this paper :

A Differential Attack Technique Against SPN Structures with Application to AES and KHAZAD (Piret & Quisquater - CHES 2003)

This paper describe how to retrieve four bytes of the last round key with at least two pairs of ciphertext/faultytext.

Each pair of ciphertext $C$ and faultytext $C^*$ could be written as $C^* = C \oplus E$, where $E$ contains 4 bytes $\neq 0$.

For more details, the attack consists on several steps :

- Compute a list $L$ of 4x255 possible differences after the MixColumns of Round 9
- Guess 4 parts of $K_{10}$
- Compute $d = SB^{-1} (C \oplus K_{10}) \oplus SB^{-1} (C^* \oplus K_{10})$
- If $d$ in $L$, add guessed $K$ in a list of possible candidates of $K_{10}$
- Repeat for each pair, considering only guessed $K$ in the list of possible candidates, if $d$ is not in $L$ for the new pair, remove the candidate.
- Repeat until the list of possible candidates is reduced to one.

Comment: A short description of the technique used should be part of the answer, so if you can add it we would be grateful.

Comment: Ah, wow, wecome to Crypto, Miss Seeluna :)

Comment: What do you mean by `Guess 4 parts of K10`, you mean `4 bytes` right? And you should already know the location of that `4 bytes` right?

Comment: Yes sorry : by parts, I mean bytes. And for the location of 4 bytes corresponds to the location of the differences between $C$ and $C^*$.